# How the Operating System manages the Stack and Heap growing and shrinking

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, kernel

I started studying operating systems and I've read about: virtual memory, paging, MMU among other things.
I know (roughly):

- A process is divided into 4 sectors: text, data, heap and stack.
- The memory is divided into two major parts: Kernel and User.

However, from the examples I've seen, they all (at least in my understanding) of two one, or show:

1. Only one process in memory:

[image]

2. Or it shows 2 processes in memory and explains about paging, swapping and etc... but doesn't say how the operating system works
   when the Heap sector is close to reaching the Stack sector (and vice versa).

**My question is: What Linux, BSD, Windows, MacOS etc... do in this situation!**

I thought of 2 things:

1. The system sends the process to another place in virtual memory (See figure 1)
2. The system has 4 huge sectors, and when a process is loaded into memory each piece of it is placed in one of these 4 parts (See figure 2)

If anyone has any answers or any reading material I would be very grateful.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first figure doesn't show one process in memory. It shows the virtual memory layout of each process. This is old information. Today, you will have a 64 bits CPU. 32 bits CPUs are mostly microcontrollers with more or less 1MB of memory. This is important because a 64 bits CPU never runs out of virtual memory. It can run out only of physical memory (RAM).

Typical desktop CPUs (mostly x86-64 by Intel or AMD), have 48 bits of virtual address space meaning 2^48 bytes (262144 GB). Since the kernel occupies half of that, it leaves each process with 131072 GB of virtual address space. The heap or stack will never grow this much.

Older 32 bits CPUs could actually have 4GB of RAM spanning their whole virtual address space. Since the kernel occupies 1GB of it, if one process occupies 3GB of virtual address space, you are running out of RAM. Your process will get killed. The stack cannot meet the heap since:

1. The stack has a maximum size.
2. If the heap of one process grows this much, there is no more RAM so the whole kernel panics or simply kills your process.

Virtual memory is defined by the page tables and by the instructions executed by the CPU. There is no physical medium containing virtual memory. For example,

```
mov 0x1234, 0x4321
```

moves the value 0x4321 to virtual address 0x1234. When the CPU executes that instruction, it crosses the page tables automatically. Virtual memory is a concept where every process has theoretical access to all the address space a CPU offers. At the end of 32 bits processors (more than 10 years ago), you did have a lot of 4GB RAM modules. At the beginning though, you could have lots of computers with smaller RAM modules. Each process still has 4GB of theoretical address space to work with. As long as every process in the system doesn't occupy more than 4GB + the size of hard-disk swap space of physical memory, the system can continue to work. With 64 bits processors, there is so much virtual memory that no existing computer has enough RAM to span all of it.

By default, the stack is given a maximum size when a process is first created. The kernel can verify that the stack doesn't overflow by leaving a non-present page underneath. If the stack tries to read or write that page, the CPU jumps to the page fault handler. This lets the kernel realize that the process is using too much stack which responds by killing it.